# How to show images in offline tablet application

Tags: android, ios, html, indexeddb, offline-caching

I'm looking for a way to create offline order entry application for Android and Apple tablets.

Application should download product list with images.

It should allow to show large product image and allow to enter ordered quantities for products.

This order entry must work also if there is no internet connection.

If internet becomes available, entered order should submitted to server.

I looked into offline Web application sample in

http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html

and searched sourceforge and codeplex for reference applications but haven't found any.

Most difficult seems to be showing offline images. In html5 application I found two possibilities:

1. Store images in Indexeddb (or in other way) and use javascript to show images 
   in tablet browser in offline mode.

   Where to find sample for this? To to convert database data to image which is displayed in tablet ?
2. Create manifest containing all image urls dynamically. Tablet browser probably then loads images into offline cache and allows to show them in offline mode.

Where to find framework or sample application which can be used as starting point ?

Should I use html5 + Indexeddb + jQuery + jQuery UI or is there better way ?

Server is Linux server running C# Mono ASP.NET MVC4 application which can provide data for this planned tablet offline application and receives orders from it. I can create WebAPI controller for application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to persist the images in your application and control the references using a database  (search for core data for iOS and greendao for Android). Anyway you will need a mechanism to download those images from server when internet connection is available to store that.

About the orders, you can store the order locally in your database and when internet is available you sync those informations with the server, that mechanism can be called whenever you want, you need to define how will be user experience.

My suggestion: Try to break your problem in small problems and try to resolve them. Your question  looks more like a general architecture question.

Here is the topics that can help you to develop these apps:

**Android:**

Database: greendao: 
http://greendao-orm.com/

Webservice/Persistence: https://github.com/koush/ion

**iOS:**
Database: Core Data: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html

Webservice/Persistence: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

I hope this help you to start.

Comment: I looks like you recommend to create different apps for Android and iOS. Why ?  html5+IndexedDB allows to create single application which runs on both. So should I use html5 form this ?

Comment: As you asked for suggestions about a better way to do that, i mentioned a native way to do this tasks.

Comment: Is GreenDAO is light weight ?? Do I have separate pojo class and DAO class for every webservice response??